# React useEffect infinite loop cause

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone explain me why my code's useEffect() getting stuck in an infinite loop? I am practicing React and implemented a user profile page. The infinite loop is triggered when I upload a picture to firebase, My thought process was that when I upload the picture, coverUrl gets changed into the url of the picture, inside useEffect if I see a change in cover, I update my userData and database value with the uploaded picture.

Globalconfig holds some state variables which gets filled up during login (in a different page) and I use it in this page but wait for it load first

```
const ProPicAndCover = () => {
const Globalconfig = useContext(ConfigContext)
const [coverUrl, setCoverUrl] = useState('')
const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    // Wait for data to load
    if(Globalconfig.userData !== ""){
        setIsReady(true)
    }

    if (coverUrl !== "") { 
        update(ref(getDatabase(),'users/' + Globalconfig.userData.UID), {cover_picture_url: coverUrl})
        getUserInfo(Globalconfig.UID, getDatabase(), Globalconfig.setUserData)
    }
},[Globalconfig.userData])

if (isReady) { 
    return(
        <div id="ProPicAndCoverContainer">  
            <Container>
                <input type="file" id="coverPhoto" hidden onChange={() => {
                    const file = document.getElementById("coverPhoto").files[0]
                    uploadImageAndgetUrl(getStorage(), file, Globalconfig.UID, setCoverUrl)
                    console.log(coverUrl)
                }}></input>
                
                {/* Code block to display if the user doo't have a cover photo */}
                <div id="coverPic" style={{display: Globalconfig.userData.cover_picture_url === '' ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
                    <div id="coverText" onClick={() => {
                        document.getElementById("coverPhoto").click()
                    }}>
                        <h2>Selct a cover photo</h2>
                        <FaUpload/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {/* Code block to display if the user have a cover photo */}
                <img src={Globalconfig.userData.cover_picture_url} id="coverPic" style={{display: Globalconfig.userData.cover_picture_url === '' ? 'none' : 'block'}}></img>

                {/*Profile Picture*/}
                <img src={Globalconfig.userData.profile_picture} id="userProfilePicture"></img>
                <h2 id="username">{Globalconfig.userData.first_name} {Globalconfig.userData.last_name}</h2>
                
                {/* User Bio */}
                <InputEditFirebase editIcon={<AiOutlineEdit/>} fireBaseObjKey="bio" fireBasePathToUpdate={"users/"+Globalconfig.userData.UID} id="bio" textValue={Globalconfig.userData.bio} inputText={"Click to add bio"} uid={Globalconfig.userData.UID}>"{Globalconfig.userData.bio}"</InputEditFirebase>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
else {
    return(
        <div className="loader">
            <div className="lds-circle"><div></div></div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React useEffect is causing infinite loop because you have given userData as an dependency in useEffect and you are also changing the value of userData inside useEffect. By fixing this it might fix our issue.

Comment: Shouldn’t it run only once? Because I am checking if the cover was updated or not and which is being updated in the render and once it updates, I need the userData to add the changes

Comment: No,  as you are checking only that `cover is empty or not` and once you upload a image cover get updated and now you are changing `userData` which is also present as a dependency in useEffect. So it is triggering infinite rendering loop.

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. I need the userData as dependency or the page doesn't load. Need to figure out a way to keep it as a dependency while checking the cover

Comment: One way can be that if there is any string property in userData like name then you can add that as dependency. Then it will not run the useEffect till that name changes.